# Is it possible to clear the Notification when using android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.mBuilder.addAction

Tags: android, notifications

I've two actions for the Notification and when the user clicks on any of the action, it opens separate Activities.

On clicking the Notification, it's cancelling but clicking on any action is not cancelling the Notification. The requirement is to close the Notification when user clicks on any action.

[image]

In the image you can see action agree and settings. Clicking on these actions I would like to close the Notification.

I've researched and searched to the best of my abilities. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a intermediate BroadcastReceiver to handle the notifications buttons (i.e. call Settings from there). 
Send the notification to the BroadcastReceiver and cancel it there